# Alternative for keyCode

Tags: javascript, keycode

I'm still at a novice level in JavaScript. I found one bug that's troubling me.

It's how keyCode doesn't seem to work on mobile devices (chrome). I just noticed that the mobile devices don't support keyCode.

I'm guessing I could do isNaN with an ! in stead of the code below but can't really figure out how to write it neatly.

```
var code = window.event.keyCode; 

if ((code > 34 && code < 41) || (code > 47 && code < 58) || (code > 95 && code < 106) || code == 8 || code == 9 || code == 13 || code == 46){ 
    window.event.returnValue = true; 
    return; 
}
```

If anyone has a suggestion, it would be highly appreciated!
Feel free to comment on that microsite as well if you want to.

Sincerely,

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery and then use `.which`

`.which` standardizes keyCode and keyValue values between browsers

```
var code = event.which
if(code === 14){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

> The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode.
>   It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input.

```
$("<input-element-id-or-name>").keyup(function(e){
     if(e.which === 14) {
         // do something
     }
});
```